# Calling jar from XQuery

Tags: jar, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have came across a situation where I have to call a jar with a string parameter and get the result. Is there any way i can able to do this? I came across a link where importing `java:java.lang.Math` namespace using Java function inside XQuery. This will help me to use library functions of Java. Is there any way I can call jar or customize function from XQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic doesn't have a way to directly call a Java method in a JAR file. The common practice is to have the required Java functionality available as a service, then call that from MarkLogic. For instance, you could set up Tomcat to host the functionality that lives in the JAR file.